# Writing Data table to pipe separated file(.psv) issue in c#

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, file-writing

I had write data table to pipe separated file (|) using below code. the problem is i had a html template in database contains **\r\n** . due to **\r\n** in data the data is getting line by line in psv file. to overcome that i had tried several ways to resolve it  but no luck..  so issue is happening at when ever i had a data containing \r\n ..does any one guess why this issue is happening.

```
public static  void start()
            {
             string filePath = @"E:\Files\2.psv;
            string ConnectionString = "server=localhost;database=sql       
                                       sample;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
            con.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[getDetailsCodeId]";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Id);
            con.Open();

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(ds);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = ds.Tables[0];
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            bool isColumnNameAppend = false;
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate,     
            FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            StreamWriter str = new StreamWriter(fs);
            int count = dt.Columns.Count;
            str.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);

           if (!isColumnNameAppend)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    sb.Append(dt.Columns[i].ColumnName + '|');
                }
                sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                isColumnNameAppend = true;
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < dt.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < dt.Columns.Count; k++)
                {
                    sb.Append(PsvQuote((dt.Rows[j][k].ToString())) + '|');
                }
                sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
            }

            str.Write(sb.ToString());
            str.Flush();
            str.Close();
            fs.Close();
          }

   public static string PsvQuote(string text)
    {
              text = String.Format("\"{0}\"", text);
              return text;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   public static string PsvQuote(string text)
    {
              text = String.Format("\"{0}\"", text.Replace("|","").Replace("\r","").Replace("\n","");
              return text;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply... but is was answered me 50% only. i am able to see only half data in psv file..remaining data was lost...

Comment: Rest of the code looks good to me.  It's a bit convoluted, but it should work fine, if you want a pipe as the last thing in each of your lines.  That's a bit unusual, but your choice.  Perhaps you need to investigate your testing method.

Comment: I have tried with below code also but getting another issue as data truncating.. i am sure that tested code but i cant find where is the issue  string.Join(" ", Regex.Split(text, @"(?:\r\n|\n|\r)"));